# Get yesterday's date in Clojure

Tags: date, clojure

I need to get yesterday's date (not user-based, but relative to the server) in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`.

What is the best way to achieve this in Clojure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With Java 8 Time API:

```
(import (java.time LocalDate)
        (java.time.format DateTimeFormatter))

(def formatter (DateTimeFormatter/ofPattern "yyyy-MM-dd"))

(def yesterday (.minusDays (LocalDate/now) 1))

(.format formatter yesterday)
;; => "2017-04-05"
```

Or with Java 8 Time API Clojure wrapper: [clojure.java-time](https://github.com/dm3/clojure.java-time)

```
(require '[java-time :as t])

(def yesterday (t/minus (t/local-date)
                        (t/days 1)))

(t/format "yyyy-MM-dd" yesterday)
;; => "2017-04-05"
```

Comment: Or just `(.minusDays (LocalDate/now) 1)`

Answer (score 6):

[clj-time](https://github.com/clj-time/clj-time)

```
(t/minus (t/now) (t/days 1))
```

Answer (score 4):

First require these in your clj file.

```
(require [clj-time.core :as t]
         [clj-time.format :as f])
```

The below code is self-explanatory. But don't use so many defs.

```
;;To Create Yesterday's date    
(def yesterday 
     (t/minus (t/now) (t/days 1)))

;; To format as YYYY-MM-DD
(def custom-formatter (f/formatter "yyyy-MM-dd"))
(def output-time 
     (f/unparse custom-formatter yesterday))
```

Here is a more functional way:

```
(defn yesterday []
   (let [yesterday-date (t/minus (t/now) (t/days 1))
         custom-formatter (f/formatter "yyyy-MM-dd")]
      (f/unparse custom-formatter yesterday-date)))
```

And then do a function call `(yesterday)`.

For further reads on clj-time refer [documentation](http://clj-time.github.io/clj-time/doc/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Without needing clj-time...

```
(let [today (.format 
               (java.text.SimpleDateFormat. "yyyyMMdd") 
                   (new java.util.Date))
      yesterday (.format 
                  (java.text.SimpleDateFormat. "yyyyMMdd") 
                     (new java.util.Date 
                       (- (System/currentTimeMillis) (* 24 60 60 1000))))]
   (println "today: " today)
   (println "yesterday: " yesterday))
```